# NotFound for HTTPS Endpoint When Decrypting HTTPS Traffic

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, https, fiddler

I'm currently developing an application in C# for Windows Phone against an HTTPS web service. An example of the endpoint that I'm accessing is as follows: https://apitest.letsfreckle.com/api/projects.json?token=lx3gi6pxdjtjn57afp8c2bv1me7g89j

When I inspect the network traffic using Fiddler with the "Decrypt HTTPS traffic" option enabled I get a "NotFound" exception in my code. If I disable the "Decrypt HTTPS traffic" option in Fiddler, then I get the response that I would expect in my code.

In Fiddler, I see the HTTP CONNECT request with a result of 200, but nothing else.

I'm using Fiddler v2.3.7.4 beta on 64-bit Windows 7 with no filters. I have no proxy servers configured and the problem persists if I disable my anti-virus protection (Microsoft Security Essentials). I have tried removing the interception certificates and the root and site-specific certificates are correctly re-created.

I appreciate that this scenario works perfectly well for the many Fiddler users out there, but would be grateful if you could shed any light on why it's not working for me.

**UPDATE:** I can hit the endpoint and get a response just fine using a browser and when not decrypting HTTPS traffic through Fiddler and when Fiddler is not involved.

Comment: I'm assuming you've installed the fiddler root certificate?

Comment: Using Firefox and Fiddler I don't see any problems calling the mentioned URL with HTTPS decryption enabled.

Comment: @Massif For Windows Phone emulator development, it's not possible to install a certificate and I've managed HTTPS decryption fine in the past.

Comment: @Robert I don't have an issue getting a response via a browser, only when decrypting HTTPS traffic when accessing via my application. It's a Fiddler issue, not the endpoint.

Comment: Do you know if the API is hosted on IIS?

Comment: @ChristiaanV I have no idea where the API is hosted, sorry. That shouldn't make a difference though, right?

Comment: Correct, sorry changed some http statuscodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the certificate on the emulator, I use an HTTPS endopoint in my app too and I can decrypt the traffic.

You need to visit with IE Mobile this URL: http://yourmachine:8888/ and click on the link "install the root certificate", after you should be able to see the traffic beyond the handshake (CONNECT)

You need to start Fiddler bedore the emulator I think.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'd tried hitting the fiddler echo service from the device to get the root certificate but it seems that you have to manually type http:// at the start of the URL; it doesn't auto-add like most browsers :)